# finding vertices of a triangle after rotating

Tags: geometry

Let say that I have an equilateral triangle with vertices: (0,0) (200,346.4) (400,0). Say I want to rotate this triangle 30 degrees clockwise, how would I find the new vertices?

Edit1: Rotating about the center of the triangle, my apologies.

Comment: You should mention the vertex/point or the axis about which the triangle is  rotated.

Comment: Are you rotating about the origin?

Comment: Yes rotating about the center of the triangle, my apologies

Comment: Are you looking for an analytic solution or a geometric one?

Comment: The actual vertices I am working on a website. -Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in the actual values or the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First subtract the coordinates of the centre, $(200,\frac{200\sqrt{3}}{3})$ from each vertex coordinate.
Then multiply each new vertex by the rotation matrix for clockwise rotation by 30 degrees, i.e. $$\left(\begin{matrix}\cos(-30)&-\sin(-30)\\\sin(-30)&\cos(-30)\end{matrix}\right)$$ to obtain three new rotated vertices.
Then add back the centre coordinates to each rotated vertex.

Comment: Nice thats what I was looking for I was actually almost there haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about solving this;

- Imagine the three points of the triangle as points on a circle
  "concentric" with the triangle.
- These points form three 120 degree arcs.
- The midpoints of these arcs are the vertices after a 60 degree
  rotation, and the quarterpoints of these arcs are the possible vertices after the two possible 30 degree rotations.

I am not at a point where I can do the calculations though, sorry. I would do this as a comment if I had that permission available to me on this stack. Hopefully this is able to point you in the right direction though!

Comment: I was thinking something about that, but my roommate suggested something along the lines of a rotational matrix where you would use each line as a vector and rotate them individually. I'll look into both.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the triangle about [b]what[/b] point?

I suspect you mean about the center of the triangle.  If that is true, the first thing you need to do is determine that center.  Fortunately, for a triangle, that is just the mean of the coordinates of the point, ((0+ 200+ 400)/3, (0+ 346.4/3))= (200, 115.5).

To determine what happens to the coordinates of a vertex when you wrote the triangle about that point:
1)  Translate the whole triangle so that the center is moved to the orgin: Subtract the coordinates of the center from the coordinates of the vertex.
(0, 0) becomes (-200, -115.5)

2) Rotate around the origin by angle [math]\theta[/tex]: 
The new x coordinate becomes [math]x'= x cos(\theta)- y sin(\theta)[/itex] and the new y coordinate [math]y'= x sin(\theta)+ y cos(\theta)[/math].
  With the values above and [math]\theta= 30[/math] degrees, [math]x'= (-200(0.8660)+ 115.5(.5)= -115.45[/math] and [math]y'= (-2oo)(.5)- 115.5(0.8660)= -200.023[/math]. That gives (-115.45, -200.023)

3) Translate back to the center- add the coordinates of the center:
(-115.45+ 200, -220.023+ 115.5)= (84.55, -104.523).